# Is there any way to ask for location permission programmatically for IOS Cordova Ionic v1?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Is there any other plugin except https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy to ask for location permission in Cordova Ionic V1 App?

Comment: What's the problem with that plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Except for location accuracy plugin we can make use of Cordova-open-native-settings plugin. If we found GPS is disabled. this Plugins help us to navigate to lacation setting option to manually unable/disable location setting.

```
 <plugin spec="https://github.com/guyromb/Cordova-open-native-settings" />

if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.settings) {
        window.cordova.plugins.settings.open("location", function () {

        },function () {
            alert('failed to open settings');
        }
 );
}
```